# Problems with including QWebView in QT application

Tags: qt, symbian, qwebview

I am using qt creator. I wanted to show a webpage inside QWebView, but my projet doesn't compile. When i want to include QWebView, editor says "no such file or directory".
My code:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QWebView>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
QApplication a(argc, argv);

QWebView view;
view.showMaximized();

return a.exec();
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you add in your Project_name.pro file in Qt Creator line like this: **QT += core gui webkit** ?

Comment: Tnx, i guess i will have to read some docs about .pro file. As it seems, i have to add something to it for every include i make in source files.